# Is success assumed with Android BluetoothGattCallback onCharacteristicWrite function if no error occurs?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Working on an Android app to send data to a peripheral device via BLE.  Question about Android BluetoothGATTCallback onCharacteristicWrite function - how does it know that the write transaction was successful?  Is success assumed so long as no error occurs?  Or does it record a success response of some sort sent from the peripheral device characteristic to which data is written?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say matdev's comments in his answer is not correct, at least according to my experience.

Assuming you use "Write With Response" (`WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT`) rather than "Write Without Response" (`WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE`), the following applies:

First you call `writeCharacteristic`. This method performs some sanity checks, such as the characteristic you are trying to write to has the "write" property, there are no other pending GATT operations on this `BluetoothGatt` object, and that the object is not closed. If those sanity checks are passed, this method returns `true`.

The write request is then transferred over the air to the remote device's GATT server. Here the request is processed and the GATT server returns a Write Response or an Error Response with an error code, which is sent back to the Android device. When Android receives a Write Response, it will call `onCharacteristicWrite` with `GATT_SUCCESS` (0) as status. If Android instead receives an Error Response, it will call `onCharacteristicWrite` and set the status to the code included in the Error Response. If the GATT server e.g. returns 0x80 (Application Error) or 0x13 (Value Not Allowed), this is the status code you will receive in your callback.

If the connection drops before the response is received, Android will call the callback with some currently undocumented non-success status code.

If you instead use "Write Without Response" (`WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE`), the behaviour of `onCharacteristicWrite` changes. Now, this callback is instead used for flow control. When the local Bluetooth stack's buffers are ready to accept another packet, this is when you will get the callback. This can happen even before the packet is sent over the air.

Comment: if I understand you correctly then, so long as the connection isn't dropped before a response is received, is it safe to assume that absent an Error Response, the write operation was successful? I ask that because I'm using a Write api (for Ionic) which doesn't return the response status code from the BLE peripheral.  Instead it returns a Promise<void>.  That's why I wanted to know if absent an error code from the peripheral (and also assuming connection to the peripheral isn't lost before the response), would it be safe to assume that the write operation is successful?

Comment: Can you give a link to that repo of that Ionic BLE wrapper?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le/blob/main/src/bleClient.ts.   Write function begins on line 458.

Comment: As you can see at https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le/blob/main/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/community/plugins/bluetoothle/Device.kt#L124, if the write is successful, the promise will be resolved. If an Error Response is received instead, the status code is thrown away but the promise will be rejected with a generic string as error.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I want to update the status in my app after a write operation, the following code would always (unless if connection is dropped before BLE peripheral returns a response) give an accurate status update, right?  `BLEClient.write(deviceID, serviceID, characteristicID, data).then(()=>{successMessage()}).catch((error)=>{errorMessage(error)})`

Comment: Yes. That seems correct.

Answer (score -1):

You can assume the BLE write transaction is successful if the status param of BluetoothGATTCallback's `onCharacteristicWrite()` equals `BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS` i.e. 0

If an error occurs, the status value will indicate the type of error, such as

```
/** GATT write operation is not permitted */
public static final int GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED = 0x3;
```

Here is an extract of the doc about `onCharacteristicWrite()`:

> Params:
> ...
> status – The result of the write operation BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS if the operation succeeds.

Comment: Thanks.  But how does the onCharacteristicWrite get the status BluetoothGATT.GATT_SUCCESS?  Is this status returned from the ble peripheral and communicated to the BluetoothGATTCallback or is it assumed to be the case by default so long as no error has occurred in the proces?

Comment: The status BluetoothGATT.GATT_SUCCESS means that the bluethooth stack of the smartphone wrote successfully on the characteristic of the BLE peripheral. That does not prevent the device to eventually throw an error, such as in case of invalid value, but this will not be notified using onCharacteristicWrite()

Comment: That sort of makes sense, but shouldn't the success status of a write operation be communicated by the BLE device as opposed to the bluethooth stack of the smartphone determining it by itself?  What if the smartphone successfully sent the data over BLE, but somehow never got written to the BLE device (this is completely different from whether the BLE device considers the data to be valid or not)?  Then wouldn't the GATT_SUCCESS status be a false positive?  Feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: If an error occurs on the BLE device related to the value written, it can notify the smartphone using onCharacteristicChanged(), maybe with a custom error code. the BLE stack does not know your logic for handling errors.